# MySQL - Save list order with single update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Is it possible to sort a list and save the order in a single update?

I tried this way:

```
UPDATE `jos_vm_category`,(SELECT @row:=0) AS init SET @row:=@row+1, list_order=@row ORDER BY `category_name` ASC
```

but got an error:

> 1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and
>   ORDER BY

If it's not clear, I need this:

```
category_id | category_name | list_order
    3       |       A       |       1
    1       |       B       |       2
    2       |       C       |       3
```

from this:

```
category_id | category_name | list_order
    1       |       B       |       1
    2       |       C       |       2
    3       |       A       |       3
```

with a single UPDATE.

So list_order is a field of the table where I have to save the order of rows. (I already have the solution, but have to wait for 2 days, so I'll publish then if nobody answers the question.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySql does not permit a `ORDER BY` with a multiple table update. [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

You can use a sub query instead:

```
UPDATE jos_vm_category c
    JOIN (
        SELECT category_id, (@row:=@row+1) rowNum
        FROM jos_vm_category, (SELECT @row:=0) dm
        ORDER BY category_name
    ) rs ON c.category_id = rs.category_id
SET c.list_order = rs.rowNum
```

Alternatively, you can split them into 2 queries:

```
SELECT @row:=0;
UPDATE jos_vm_category
SET list_order = (@row:=@row+1)
ORDER BY category_name;
```

Comment: I know this is old but the UPDATE statement you posted is the greatest SQL statement to ever be posted.  It was exactly what I'd been looking for over a half year to find.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain how this SQL statements working?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
ALTER TABLE `jos_vm_category` ORDER BY `category_name`;
```

Comment: Not really, I need the row numbers of the ordered list.

Comment: There is the built in SQL function `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Is that what you are looking for instead of `@row`? [http://www.openwinforms.com/row_number_to_sql_select.html](http://www.openwinforms.com/row_number_to_sql_select.html)

Comment: MySQL does not support windowing functions, so row_number() cannot be used